# How to get text response in survey monkey via API

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm currently getting responses from SurveyMonkey using the v3 APIs...

I'm using the `/collectors/{id}/responses/{id}/details` call and I successfully getting the resp. BUT the resp has got the IDs and not the text values e.g.

```
           {
                "id": "111788228",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "choice_id": "828117913"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

1) Can I get SM to send me the text answer?

2) If I can't how can I get the text value using the choice_id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now there is ['bulk' API](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs?api_key=3yr7n6m8sjwvm48x8nhxej52#api-endpoints-get-surveys-id-responses-bulk).

Look at the 'simple' option:

```
GET /surveys/{id}/responses/bulk?simple=true
```

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a way currently to get the Survey text directly with the responses. You'll have to fetch the [survey details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-details) or the details for a [specific question](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-pages-id-questions-id) and match the choice ID with the text for that choice on your own.

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>
```

or

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/pages/<page_id>/questions/<question_id>
```

You'll get a body back with the choices like this:

```
{
    ...
    "answers": {
        "choices": [{
            "id": "12345",
            "visible": true,
            "is_na": false,
            "text": "Apples",
            "position": 1
        }, ...]
    },
    ...
}
```

Then you can just match the `id` field with the `choice_id` field from the response.