# Survey Monkey Api - Get label text for response choice_id

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm grabbing survey responses using `"/surveys/" . $id . "/responses/bulk"`.  For multiple choice questions, how do I include the label text for a response? Only `choice_id` is given.  I've looked in the document and can't seem to find a clue.

Thanks!

Dylan

Comment: There's a few questions about that in stackoverflow I believe, the most recent one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531083/how-to-get-text-response-in-survey-monkey-via-api

Answer (score 1):

Use the following API endpoint pattern to fetch all the information on the question, including the selects:

```
https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/pages/{page_id}/questions/{question_id}
```